# Export SQL Azure database to local machine

Tags: sql-server, azure

What's the fastest way to export out a SQL Azure database (so I can restore it in my development environment)? I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio > right click on database name > Tasks > Export Data Tier Application. It then exports it into a .bacpac file on my local machine.

However this process takes a long time (almost 1 hour for large databases). Is there a faster process available?

I do not have an Azure storage account so I can't use the Export function in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way would be to export the DB to a bacpac on a storage account then download the bacpac to your local machine to re-import.  If a azure storage account is not an option, then yes the only way is the way you are doing it now.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export
Export to a Stogare Account because use the same Data Center in the same azure region and the transference it's very faster. Then you can download the bacpac from azure portal or use the Storage Explorer tool: http://storageexplorer.com/